# Subversion with TortoiseSVN overlays not showing read-only for directories

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We're using Subversion with tortoiseSVN, and we have used the auto property 'svn:needs-lock' when we add files to the repository.

When we check the project out of the repository, all of the files come down with the grey tick (read-only property), but the folders all keep the green tick.

is it possible to show the folders with the read-only (grey tick) also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because a folder is never read-only.

Comment: I was hoping to get an indication of which folders contained files which were writable, from the top level. But as the folder could never be read-only i guess this wouldn't work. Cheers for the Answer though.